# Make inline JS variable available to loaded JS file

Tags: javascript, variables

I am getting a variable X in my .pug file and I want to pass it to a separate JS file, how can I do this?

```
html 
    head 

//Importing Javascript file 
    script(type='text/javascript')
         include ../api/public/javascript/dashboard.js
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

    body 
        script.
            var i = "#{variableX}"
```

I want to share this variable coming from the server with my JS file located in another folder, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain this share thing? Share variable in frontend?

Comment: Yes, it would make the JS file have variable access. So that the separate file can read this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not pug relevant now.

You could add the variable to the global window object, which all JS files would then have access to. Just note the sequence of initialization and loading of the JS files.

To be sure, you should only access them when everything is fully loaded.

pug file:

```
body 
    script.
        window.myVaraibelX = "#{variableX}"
```

other js file:

```
console.log(window.myVaraibelX || 'not initialized yet');
```

other js file with `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function () {
  console.log(window.myVaraibelX);
}
```

Comment: In my case, the variable represents a Session Token, I believe it is not right to add it in the window global object. My approach was to turn it into a session cookie. What is your opinion?

Comment: Cookie or localStorage or sessionStorage ...